# Status check is not running on Pull Request creation

Tags: github

Something has happened an my status check that normally runs for a particular branch is not running. I have branch protection setup with the correct workflow.

[image: branch protection with status check]

This used to work. I can run the workflow manually and it completes successfully. The pull request does not appear to trigger it at all. I can't see any logs of it.

[image]

Any ideas why my status check would stop working?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The branch name in the workflow was incorrect. It was pointing at main when this repository uses master. There is no history of changes to this workflow, yet it worked in the past. You can see the workflow was kicked off by PRs in the past, so something changed. Oh well. I am glad that I was able to figure it out.

[image]